# Django - iterate number in for loop of a template

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I have the following for loop in my django template displaying days. I wonder, whether it's possible to iterate a number (in the below case i) in a loop. Or do I have to store it in the database and then query it in form of days.day_number?

```
{% for days in days_list %}
    <h2># Day {{ i }} - From {{ days.from_location }} to {{ days.to_location }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 904, accepted):

Django provides it. You can use either:

- `{{ forloop.counter }}` index starts at **1**.
- `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` index starts at **0**.

In template, you can do:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ forloop.counter }} # starting index 1
    {{ forloop.counter0 }} # starting index 0

    # do your stuff
{% endfor %}
```

More info at: [for | Built-in template tags and filters | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: But it gives length-1.

Comment: What about nested for loops? How can we tell django if we want to count the inner or the outer loop?

Comment: @crey4fun, check `forloop.parentloop` refer docs for more info.

Comment: What if I need to append the index to a string?

Answer (score 165):

Also one can use this:

```
{% if forloop.first %}
```

or

```
{% if forloop.last %}
```

Comment: Not the answer to the question, but still the answer for many people that will search for this question. Good stuff!

Comment: Great answer. Helped a lot. Just got an exception because I was using Jinja 2. In case you have same issue, with Jinja 2 you can use {{ loop.index }} (indexing starts at 1)

Answer (score 21):

```
{% for days in days_list %}
    <h2># Day {{ forloop.counter }} - From {{ days.from_location }} to {{ days.to_location }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

or if you want to start from 0

```
{% for days in days_list %}
        <h2># Day {{ forloop.counter0 }} - From {{ days.from_location }} to {{ days.to_location }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I upvoted because it shows how to specifically answer the question. Although it is not a general ansswer, it gives an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 10):

from the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#for
you can found it to count items you can use a counter like this

```
{% for job in jobs %}
<td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
<td>{{ job.title }}</td>
<td>{{ job.job_url }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

- `{{ forloop.counter }}` start counting from `1`
- `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` start counting from `0`

Answer (score 4):

Do like this,

```
{% for days in days_list %}
    <h2># Day {{ forloop.counter }} - From {{ days.from_location }} to {{ days.to_location }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Django HTML template doesn't support index as of now], but you can achieve the goal:

If you use **Dictionary** inside Dictionary in views.py then iteration is possible using key as index. example:

```
{% for key, value in DictionartResult.items %} <!-- dictionartResult is a dictionary having key value pair-->
<tr align="center">
    <td  bgcolor="Blue"><a href={{value.ProjectName}}><b>{{value.ProjectName}}</b></a></td>
    <td> {{ value.atIndex0 }} </td>         <!-- atIndex0 is a key which will have its value , you can treat this key as index to resolve-->
    <td> {{ value.atIndex4 }} </td>
    <td> {{ value.atIndex2 }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Elseif you use **List** inside dictionary then not only first and last iteration can be controlled, but all index can be controlled. example:

```
{% for key, value in DictionaryResult.items %}
    <tr align="center">
    {% for project_data in value %}
        {% if  forloop.counter <= 13 %}  <!-- Here you can control the iteration-->
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <td bgcolor="Blue"><a href={{project_data}}><b> {{ project_data }} </b></a></td> <!-- it will always refer to project_data[0]-->
            {% else %}
                <td> {{ project_data }} </td> <!-- it will refer to all items in project_data[] except at index [0]-->
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

End If ;)

//
Hope have covered the solution with Dictionary, List, HTML template, For Loop, Inner loop, If Else.
Django HTML Documentaion for more methods: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 0):

I think you could call the id, like this

```
{% for days in days_list %}
    <h2># Day {{ days.id }} - From {{ days.from_location }} to {{ days.to_location }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```