# Iteration number of for loop in a template

Tags: django

In a Django template, I want to create a for loop that iterates through a list. During that loop, I also want to be able to use the iteration number of the loop.

For example, if `some_list` has 4 elements, then:

```
{% for o in some_list %}
    # Print out the iteration number
{% endfor %}
```

Should print out the following:

```
>> 0
>> 1
>> 2
>> 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - iterate number in for loop of a template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481499/django-iterate-number-in-for-loop-of-a-template)

Answer (score 6):

See the docs for the [for tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for).  To get the loop index use `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` inside the block.