# How to use the current index to get the value of another array?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481499/django-iterate-number-in-for-loop-of-a-template), and I have an array like that:

```
context[u'erreurs'] = {
    'aa': {'titres': [], 'liste': [], 'urls': []},
    'bb': {'titres': [], 'liste': [], 'urls': []},
    '...': {'titres': [], 'liste': [], 'urls': []}
}
```

If there's an error, `'titres'`, `'liste'` and `'urls'` become array of strings, filled with adequates values.

In my template, if erreur is set I do this:

```
    {% for idx, tab in erreurs.items %}
        <ul>
        {% for e in tab.liste %}
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{{ tab.urls[forloop.counter0] }}">{{ e }}</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li>{{ e }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

I would like to use the current index to use the value that is in another array, here: `tab.urls`. It doesn't work and gives me the error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[forloop.counter0]' from 'tab.urls[forloop.counter0]'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Django's templates don't support such syntax. You should put together a custom template filter:

```
# yourapp/templatetags/yourapp_tags.py:
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def at_index(array, index):
    return array[index]
```

and use it like:

```
{% load yourapp_tags %}
{{ tab.urls|at_index:forloop.counter0 }}
```

Comment: Ok, but I'm asking for a workaround, or maybe a suggestion how to do it? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an actual model that represents the data then the task becomes trivial

```
class YourModel(object):
    titre = ''
    liste = '' 
    url = ''

context[u'erreurs'] = {
    'aa': [],  # List of model
}

{% for idx, tab in erreurs.items %}
    <ul>
    {% for model in tab %}
        {{ model.titre }}
        {{ model.liste }}
        {{ model.url }}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but `titre`, `liste` and `url` are arrays so I cant handle them like this.

Comment: @OlivierPons - sure you can, its just a pre-processing step to convert the three arrays into one object array before assigning to the context