# How to read the contents of drop-down menus in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have two drop-down menus and I want to retrieve its values to use them as variables to filter the retrieved data from an internal Web API.

[image: Dropdown menus]

**Views.py**

```
# I want to retrieve the year and week number, so I can use them as values in my filter
def filter():
    filters = {"filter": {
        "filters": [{
            "field": "DateTime",
            "operator": "gte",
            "value": "2017-07-23 23:59:59"
        }, {
            "field": "DateTime",
            "operator": "lte",
            "value": "2017-08-18 23:59:59"
        }],
        "logic": "and"
    }}
```

I did not use Django forms because I am not holding any other data than the years and I am generating the number of weeks, however, if you consider that it might be useful to use Django forms to facilitate the data handling then write your point of view, I want to make this web app better.

**header.html**

```
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <h6>Select year</h6>
    <select name="select_year">
      <option value = "2016" >2016</option>
      <option value = "2017"> 2017</option>
      <option value = "2018"> 2018</option>
    </select>
      <h6>Select week</h6>
      <select name="select_week">
      <!--range is not supported: the spaces represent the number of weeks -->
     {% for week in "                                                    " %}
        <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{forloop.counter}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**Caveat**: I am concerned that the code to generate the week numbers is totally incorrect because it is not the right solution and I have read the following posts [Numeric loops in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481499/django-iterate-number-in-for-loop-of-a-template), [Iterate number in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates) but this is out off topic and my priority is to get the values of these two dropdown menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
        week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)

        # rest of the code
```

Add an action to the `form` in html template and a `urlpattern` for it in Django, which is handled by `your_view` method.
The `request` object stores the data in `POST` dictionary, with keys based on html tag `names`.

You can then pass these values to your `filter` method to format the filters as you wish to.

Note: It's probably better to use [Django Forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) as it saves writing the HTML code and sanitize the values too.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

Comment: Working in this now but I will have to make some changes to my existing code. I will try to implement the Django Forms because I agree with your comment about sanitizing the values.

Comment: I am working in the implementation but I need to change some parts of the code because I will have to implement the Django forms. I will accept the answer as soon as I have implemented it.