# How do I add an incremental ID to my td?

Tags: python, html, django, count

My html file generates a table:

```
{% for resp in results %}
    <tr style="counter-increment: count">
         <td>{{ resp }}</td>
         <td>{{ resp.Question_id.Statement }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I assign an id to the first td every time a new row is generated?

Comment: What `id`? That of the `Question`? Or just the index of the `for` loop? Furthermore the syntax hints that you used `Question_id` as a `ForeignKey`, which is not really the way one is supposed to name a relation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481499/django-iterate-number-in-for-loop-of-a-template#11481619

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - iterate number in for loop of a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481499/django-iterate-number-in-for-loop-of-a-template)

Comment: i want the first td to have an id so it would look like <td id="1"></td>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `forloop.counter` [template var](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{% for resp in results %}
    <tr style="counter-increment: {{ forloop.counter }}">
         <td>{{ resp }}</td>
         <td>{{ resp.Question_id.Statement }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
forloop.counter The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)
```

More info at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ forloop.counter }} {# starting index 1 #}
    {{ forloop.counter0 }} {# starting index 0 #}

    {# do your stuff #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's probably better to refer to the current documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for