# How can I define variable in django template engine

Tags: python, django

How can I define variable in django template engine and change it while iteration? I want to create panel for posts management that I get from database and display them in table. then I want to set counter for table and for each post that I get from db increase it by one But I don't know how to define and set variable in template engine.

Comment: Did you look at the {{ forloop.counter }}? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481499/django-iterate-number-in-for-loop-of-a-template

Comment: Solved. I didn't know that. anyway thanks