# How to assemble a variable name in Django templating language?

Tags: django, variables, django-templates

I am trying to assemble a variable in Django template in that way: 
`obj.length.forloop.counter` where the `foorloop.counter` should return the number.
for example `obj.length.1` then `obj.length.2` and so on...

I tried the add filter:
`obj.length|add:forloop.counter` but that returned nothing at all.
Is there any way that I can assemble variable names like that in django templating language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - iterate number in for loop of a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481499/django-iterate-number-in-for-loop-of-a-template)

Comment: @michjnich No, what I am trying to do is `obj.length.1` , then `obj.length.2` so I want that value of 1 or 2 to be appended to the variable name itself then to get the value of that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might register a custom filter (cf. [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/)) to achieve what you want:

```py
@register.filter()
def get(obj, attr):
    if hasattr(obj, attr):
        return getattr(obj, attr)
    return obj[attr]
```

You could then use it like that in your template:

```py
{{ obj.length|get:forloop.counter }}
```

This being said, I wonder if you could not directly iterate `obj` or `obj.length` itself. Are you sure you cannot do something like that in your template? That would be much cleaner.

```py
{% for item in obj %}
    {% comment %}Do something with item{% endcomment %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That should work, but actually it didn't because the variable contains JSON.
I explained my question in details there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736058/how-to-assemble-the-variable-name-to-use-data-from-jsonfield-inside-the-template
if you can help :)